# Leaflet - about setView and LatLng cordinates of the tileLayerimages

Tags: javascript

Im working on a game. And i use Leaflet as a gamemap. And the code for the map is here:

http://pastebin.com/uFNi75kk

I use:
var london = new L.LatLng(-35, 20); 
_map.setView(london, 3);

...to load view on map. It loads the Latitude / Longidute (LatLng)

Now i want to get the LatLng cordinates of the images/tileLayers leftTop Corner that is loaded by image.php Because i want to center the screen near the gameusers castle writen on the map with image.php.

Is there a way to get the LatLng cordinates fot the image (tileLayer) ?

There is no id or name for the tileLayer so i dont know how to do this..

How should i do this? I need help!

Best Regards

Comment: alert(myMarker2.getLatLng()); pastebin.com/Di4w3DfU shows LatLng cordinates of a icon (image loaded over the map). But i still want the LatLng for the tileLayer images so i can setView the screen programatically. Because i cant load 50000-100000icons clientside. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't be simpler retrieve the castle coordinates? Is the castle an image fused with the tile? In this case wouldn't be more correct to extract the castle and put it on the map as an interactive object that has specific coordinates?

Comment: I could place the castle as an icon if thats what you ment. A image over the map. Then there are two problems. One how do i place the castle on the map? By clicking? Then it would work. But i rather place the castle on the map programmatically. And in my code i've done it by placeing a castle on the tileLayer. And it gets loaded by image.php. Therefore the castle only loads when the tileLayer is loaded on the map. Not at all times. Because if i want 50.000 or 100.000 castles on the map by loading it as i understood you ment. Then the problem two appares.

Comment: I have to load that many icons. And those icons are loaded clientside. So it will be a shitload of extra code. My solution is that i need to place the castle on the map in the beginning of the game by gameuser. So that it can save the cordinates of where the castle is placed. And this is really the thing i want to do programmatically by getting cordinates of the tileLayer where the castle is loaded. Thanks for your time. !

Comment: It seems that in some way you want to interact with castles, but not creating them as (example) markers.
If the problem is that you have 500.000 castles and not want to create them at once, you better do a spacial intersection between the map visible bounds (the part that the user is vieweing) and the records on db, so you will add and remove markers only for the visible part of the map. If this solution is inapplicable, please let me know the workflow of your application so maybe I can help you better.

Comment: That is a solution. Then i don't need to load all the castles at once. But then is the question.. How do i put the markers on the map without knowing cordinates? Then i still need to get LatLng for placeing the castles on the map. Thats why i wanted to know the cordinates of the tileLayer. Because i dont have the cordinates..hehe Thats why i think i need to let the user to place the castle on the map in the start of the game. To get the LatLng cordinates. Even if i dont want to do that. Do you understand? =)

Comment: And just so you know. Every player only gets one castle. And in that castle there is a village. And in the village they build buildings and stuff. So thats why letting the user place their castle on the map in the beginning of the game would be a solution. Even if i don't want that.

Comment: Just to know: the principle of your game is that, when a user register, he gets his own "place" in which he will build his castle? And the position of that place is totally random and determined programmatically by the server itself?

Comment: Yes that is how it's ment to be

Comment: If the game was mine, I would set an origin coordinate, then for every user that sign in, I would randomly add a constant amount of latitude and longitude until the calculated location is not already assigned to another user. This will keep the users sufficiently near to reach themselves during the game and optimises space and organise castles in a virtual grid. And finally, you will have the coordinate of each castle.

Comment: Thats a good idea! Thanks for the help! [solved]